# Why can I not add the domain Administrators group to local Administrators group on Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012

I noted that it's possible to configure `Users and Groups` on servers that do not operate as a DC, but this area is disabled on DCs. I figure that the `DOMAIN\Administrator` group is automatically given permissions to log into all DCs.

However, it appears that you **can** customize the `Users and Groups` on servers that do not operate as DCs. Why is this the case? And, why am I unable to add the `DOMAIN\Administrators` group to the local `Administrators` group on a server that isn't a DC?

Comment: `However, it appears that you can customize the Users and Groups on servers that do not operate as DCs. Why is this the case?` - Why wouldn't this be the case? What's your concern about this? `why am I unable to add the DOMAIN\Administrators group to the local Administrators group on a server that isn't a DC?` - You'll need to give us specific information about the problem you're having doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Is the new server a clean install or a vm clone? I have read an issue where a user used the same vm-disk to install the dc and a member server. he couldn't add domain users /domain admins to the local admin group.